# Какой тег добавить в block или display чтобы тег left сработал

Tags: css

У меня в css есть такой код:

```
.block-1-text {
    
    float: left;
    left: 60%;
    color: black;
}
```

И мне нужно чтобы сработал тег left. Для этого как я знаю нужен тег display: или block:. Вопрос: что поставить чтобы заработал left?

Comment: Прописать требуемый position

Comment: Спасибо, а то в этом я все время путаюсь